# Using a bit column in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I am writing a very simple query where I need to retrieve the records based on a column that has two values: 0 and 1.  I didn't realize this column has a bit type, therefore when I write the query SQL Server is giving me the message

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Primary'."

My query is simple:

```
select * from [table name]
where Primary = '1'
```

I've tried searching the site but couldn't find a good answer.  BTW, I only have access to retrieve the data from the table.  I can't declare variables or create a stored procedure or any of that stuff.  Surely this can't be that complicated.  Please assist!

Comment: I have to ask, your SO user name is for the Kansas City Chiefs?

Comment: You don't need to quote numbers or bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PRIMARY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is reserved word and it needs to be quoted:

```
select * from [table name] where [Primary] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with the datatype being a `bit`, the error, in fact, is telling you *exactly* what the problem is:

> Incorrect syntax near the **keyword 'Primary'**.

Emphasis added.

`PRIMARY` is a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Ideally don't use keywords for object names, but if you "must" then you *must* delimit identify the object. In fact, really you should avoid any names for objects that require delimit identifing:

```sql
SELECT {Your Columns} --Define the columns, don't use *
FROM dbo.[Table Name] --I hope you don't have white space in your object names too
WHERE [Primary] = 1; --Don't wrap bit/numerical values in quotes.
```

Comment: I will actually write out the columns I will be using; this was just a quick way to get the information in a hurry so I could see how all of the data resides in the columns.

Answer (score -1):

That's because `primary` is [a reserved word in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You would need to quote it:

```
select * from [table name] where [Primary] = 1
```

I would warmly recommend changing the column name so it does not conflict with a langauge keyword. There are less than 200 reserved works in SQL Server, which leaves a lot of room for alternatives.

So:

```
sp_rename '[table name].[primary]', 'prim', 'COLUMN';
```

Comment: I didn't create the table and I don't have the access to alter tables and change the structure.  Thanks though!

Comment: While good advice for designing the schema, changing the database structure due to bad query syntax in one query is massively overkill, especially when we can easily escape keywords.